# Complexity Of A Recurrence Summation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, trees

I was trying to find all possible full trees as a recurrence formula and I found it but now I want to find the complexity of it as $\theta$ relation. I found that it is something like this.

$$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(i)*f(n-i-1) \text{ and } f(0)=1,f(1)=1$$

I know it is not exactly this function (I simplified it) but if I can learn how to solve this I can apply it to all possible full trees formula.

TLDR; I want to know how I can find time complexity of $f(n)$

Comment: Now, rest is building memoization that each f(i) is calculated once. note the Catalan numbers

Comment: I am not familiar with the Catalan numbers and I can't see the relation. Will you able to show a formal proof

Comment: Here [total number of possible Binary Search Trees and Binary Trees with n keys](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/total-number-of-possible-binary-search-trees-with-n-keys/)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being 2 years late lol. My math has improved since and I now saw the relation with the catalan numbers. If you post it as an answer indicating that this has same complexity as catalan numbers I will accept it

Comment: No probs. You write it and I'll up vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Catalan numbers as @kelalaka said was the answer. If modeled correctly many problems like number off all possible binary tree's could be looked in this Catalan numbers perspective.
here is [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) detail.

Comment: Continue to contribute. You will learn lots of new ideas.